# Unity load and add animation controller dynamically

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

My code now:

```
Animator ContainerAnimator = this.GetComponent<Animator>();
ContainerAnimator.runtimeAnimatorController = Resources.Load("Assets/Cube") as RuntimeAnimatorController;
ContainerAnimator.Play("ContainerMoveUp");
```

I've got some dynamically created objects which have animators. these animators still don't have a controller in there which I'm trying to add, and it doesn't appear to work. any tips or tricks to do this? google is running out of answers

Comment: Where did you put the animation controller?

Comment: straight in the assets folder.

Comment: What's the name of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Resources.Load("Assets/Cube")` is likely returning null.

1. You have to put the animation controller in a folder called "Resources" in the Assets folder. You must spell that correctly. Move your animation Contoller into this "Resources" folder.
2. After this, remove the "Assets/" from the `Resources.Load` function. The path to pass to that should be a relative path in the Resources folder.

If the animation controller name is "Cube", you can then load it like this:

```
Resources.Load("Cube")
```

instead of:

```
Resources.Load("Assets/Cube")
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be loading the asset from the wrong directory or misplaced the filename. Here, you just remove the `Assets/` prefix from the code to resolve the issue.

You can try the following implementation as well.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayAnimationDemo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]  
    Animator anim; // refer the animator via inspector

    void Start() {
        PlayAnimation(anim, "Cube", "ContainerMoveUp");
    }

    // animator is the animator object referred via inspector
    // fileName is the animator controller file name which should put under the Resources folder
    // animName is the animation clip name, you want to play
    void PlayAnimation(Animator animator, string fileName, string animName) {
        animator.runtimeAnimatorController = Resources.Load(fileName) as RuntimeAnimatorController;
        animator.Play(animName);
    }
}
```